# How is the RKHS norm related to sample complexity or other learning theory properties?

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory

This is a somewhat soft question. Given two reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces (RKHSs) $H_1$ and $H_2$, if their RKHS norms only differ by a constant, i.e., $C_1\|f\|_{H_1}\le \|f\|_{H_2} \le C_2\|f\|_{H_1}$, where $C_1,C_2>0$. What can we say about the sample complexity or other learning theory properties?

Thank you!